# Why the browser is failing to set the cookies when header instructs it to do so?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, browser, axios

I have been trying to set a cookie in the browser and have failed. I cannot understand the reason, the cookie is not stored in the browser.

I have a setup at my local machine, where I am trying this. So the server and client both are at `localhost` but working on different ports. Here is the request that I make:

```js
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3001/server/demo', {
    lang: this.state.language,
    url: this.state.url
}).then(res => {
    // do other stuff ;
});
```

and this is the response that I get back from the server, which has the cookie header
[image]

As you see, the server wants the browser to set three cookies namely `demo`, `url` and `lang`. But none is being setup. What is exactly happening? What else is required here?

Comment: This even does not work when hosted on my server with a domain name